# Relative img src is resolved as absolute... what am I missing?

Tags: html, image, relative-path, src, absolute-path

In my project users can enter the URL of a website and the system goes and fetches all images from this website. Because the `src` of the image can be relative, the system "normalizes" it, so:

- an image with src="http://host.com/image1.png" becomes "http://host.com/image1.png" (no change)
- an image with src="/image2.png" becomes "http://host.com/image2.png" (prepend host)
- an image on "http://host.com/sub/dir/page.html" with src="image3.png" becomes "http://host.com/sub/dir/image3.png" (prepend host and path)

Now take a look at this page if you may:

http://www.presentkuriren.se/presenter/4/728/Karlek/Pasta---hjartan.html

If you have a look at the source code, the main image is implemented as `<img src="prodbilder/large/JJI10002.jpg"...`

This would lead me to the conclusion that the absolute path is http://www.presentkuriren.se/presenter/4/728/Karlek/prodbilder/large/JJI10002.jpg, which it is not. It's http://www.presentkuriren.se/prodbilder/large/JJI10002.jpg and all browsers seem to understand that and display it correctly...

I'm slightly baffled and feel like I'm missing something obvious... please point it out to me!

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this is a problem?

Comment: Didn't I state the problem clearly in the second last paragraph?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's the `<base />` tag in the head:

```
<base href="http://www.presentkuriren.se/">
```

So all relative URLs (from images, links, ...) are relative to this one!